# Is this safe to eat? (Egg)

Tags: food-safety, eggs

5 organic medium egg yolks + 80g organic cow butter. Stirred on LOWEST heat.

First its very liquid, then it thickens as you can see here https://emalm.com/?v=Fn4vm

If I continue stirring, I get tired, so I increase the heat to be done with it, which outputs scrambled eggs.

What's in the video looks more delicious than scrambled eggs, so I want to eat that.

But I don't know if its cooked/safe enough to eat at that point. In terms of salmonella and other stuff.

Even if I had a food thermometer, I don't think I can get an accurate measurement.

Is it possible to tell from that video if its safe to eat based on its thick texture?

Comment: Please don’t remove the content - it will be deleted in due time, don’t worry.

Comment: @Stephie: the question you linked to has info on mitigating the issue, but it’s about raw eggs.  It doesn’t specifically mention if this is safe, or address the issue of if there’s a specific point that you need to cook eggs to for them to to be safe

Comment: @Joe I merely commented on the OP removing the content. There’s also a second post on the topic. Just saying.